# TypeScript method overload – problem with types

Tags: typescript

I created class for converting methods from auto-generated services to common type:

```js
class ServiceHandler {

    constructor(
        private _service: Service,
        private _config: ServiceHandlerConfig
    ) {
    }
    // ...implementation
}
```

Config type looks like this (I used generic type for `id` because in some cases it was a number):

```js
interface ServiceHandlerConfig {
    updateMethod: <ID = string>(id: ID) => string;
}
```

One day I decided to implement my own service instead of use generated ones. Service which I wanted to convert may looks like this:

```js
class Service {
    update(id: string): string {
        return '';
    }
}
```

And usage of `ServiceHandler`:

```js
class App {

    serviceHandler: ServiceHandler;

    constructor(
        private _service: Service,
    ) {
        this.serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(_service, {
            updateMethod: _service.update // Getting error here
        })
    }
}
```

Currently there is an error `Type '(id: string) => string' is not assignable to type '<ID = string>(id: ID) => string'. Types of parameters 'id' and 'id' are incompatible. Type 'ID' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

It worked fine with generated services so I was surprised that I'm getting this error. After comparing my implementation with generated services I noticed that I don't use method overloading (cause there is no need). After adding two or more (one is not enough) overloads to my method the error has disappeared:

```js
class Service {
    update(id: string): string;
    update(id: string): string;
    update(id: string): string {
        return '';
    }
}
```

My question is: what TypeScript overloading does under the hood that we can see such a behaviour? I'm attaching link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PaBvAUNf0A9IdAK4AOAJmAC7wAUqlAXNBDYqgHYDmAlK3adeAbiIkAql2AB7ALZz4XGtBozoPeCs6VoMgGbQkiGYjwFiZKrQZNBHbv3vCeI8-grU6jFmwe8BPxdsdwJ8RC1SRC5oAHJYtzCAXxwUnG46RH0wDDgkNAwACTAuShAkAGEZLn1UHhCwzxsAWS0ACxlfAB4ASQARaABeIMcAPh9Wfr4h0ZHRVJwcUEgYBBR0eGLS8sQQ0NkuIVJgNUR6ULDyTmQbaAB9CHyN1jWC+AAaC4Ir1Bu6e4OtR4LyeRRKZUq1SBoWmuGSoUsADpkag5ORyoplLRUNUFktwFBoABBcjkPZhR7rMHbJAgqmbcE7Nz7apHE6mc5hS7XW4PUHwOlvT5hWFffA0NqoCCIylvLYQ3bDLjwADueXp8p29D59PeDS5BqadFaEs6rB1b0RRvgYugST4oRSKSAA)

Comment: The code is confusing before we even look at overloads.  If id is a number "in some cases", why are you accepting only `string`? Your definition of `updateMethod` *must* accept any input the caller wants to send.  Overloads are known to loosen type checking, but I'm not sure what the point of your code is here.  Maybe you've got the generic scoped incorrectly and you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv1A4m) instead?